# I cant use event in fuctions in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a calculator with the help of tkinter. I have defined a function click, which returns the value the user clicked but it is giving a error which I am not understanding.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: click() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
```

My code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

def click(event):
    text = event.widget.cget("text")

icon = r"C:\Users\Sumit\vs code python\projects\tkinter_course\calculator.ico"
root = Tk()
root.configure(bg = "black")

root.geometry("644x500")
root.title("Calculator by Arnav")
root.wm_iconbitmap(icon)

scvalue = StringVar()
scvalue.set("")
screen = Entry(root, textvar=scvalue, font="lucida 37 bold")
screen.pack(fill=X, ipadx=8, pady=10, padx=12)
    
f1 = Frame(root, bg = 'white' ).pack(side = LEFT)

b1 = Button(f1 , text = "1", font = 'lucida 35 bold',command=click).pack(anchor = 'nw',side = 
LEFT, padx = 23)


b2 = Button(f1 , text = "2", font = 'lucida 35 bold',command=click).pack(anchor = 'nw',side = 
LEFT, padx = 23)


b3 = Button(f1 , text = "3", font = 'lucida 35 bold',command=click).pack(anchor = 'nw',side = 
LEFT, padx = 23)

root.mainloop()
```

It is telling that I have not defined event, but I have.
Pls help.

Comment: `event` is only passed when you `bind` the widgets. And it is passed _implicitly_ by tkinter.

Comment: so how do I do it?\

Comment: Why do you need `event`?

Comment: to get the text of button when clicked

Comment: You don't need `event` for that, you can define `b2` such that it is not `None` and then `print(b2['text'])` to get the text

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Sumit\vs code python\projects\tkinter_course\calculator.py", line 4, in click
    print(b2['text'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: this error is coming

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241138/discussion-between-arnav-tripathi-and-cool-cloud).

Comment: I told you to make it such that it is not `None`, follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name

Comment: thanks i got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your function to the widget you want to detect with this line of code...

```
<Button-Variable-Name-Here>.bind("<Button-1>", click)
```

This will then check if the widget is ever clicked with the left mouse button.